# How can I get Date and Time of exactly 24Hrs later?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used "DateTime.now()" to get today's date which works completely fine.

Now I want to get the exact date and time which will be after 24hrs. How can I do that? \

Eg. DateTime.now() = startDate = 2023-03-**28** T11:53:52.459311
endDate = 2023-03-**29** T11:53:52.459311

(ps. I am making a 24hrs validator in for the booking model that's why I need it)

Please let me know what I can do to solve this? Or if there's a better way to do it it'll be great. Thank you!

Comment: Be aware that what you're asking for is literally 24 hours later, regardless of daylight saving time changes.  That is, "24 hours later" from 2023-03-11 08:00 PST will be 2023-03-11 09:00 PDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just add 1 day Duration:

```
print(DateTime.now());
print(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)));
```

Comment: Dunno why this is getting voted down.  Even the docs say that adding one day is exactly specified as adding 24 hours.